# Deploying laravel project to server?

Tags: linux, windows, laravel-4

Firstly, I have deployed a Laravel project from Windows to server by copying everything in my Laravel folder and upload them to server, after configuring .htaccess, it ran successfully.

And then, I added a new package named "dompdf" by using command line, and it ran successfully in my Windows local. But I don't know how to deploy this package to linux server. I have tried but it failed.

Do I have to install composer on the Linux server?

Do I need to re-install again on the Linux server?

Comment: Why dont you just copy the whole website over again? (Not ideal - but you started this way - so you might as well continue)

Comment: it takes a lot of time. ): and I don't know whether It works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked some people. But they have always said that "you have to install composer on Linux server". But I realize that I do not need to install anything at all. I just uploaded and override file app/config/app.php  and some folders in the vendor folder that are new or changed after I added the package "dompdf".

Sorry about my English. If something is wrong, please correct it for me.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the package using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org):

1) Require this package in your `composer.json`:

```
'barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.4.*'
```

2) do a composer update from your terminal: `php composer.phar update`

3) After updating composer, add the ServiceProvider to the providers array in `app/config/app.php`

```
'Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider',
```

4) You can optionally use the facade for shorter code. Add this to your facades:

```
'PDF' => 'Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade',
```

Comment: I did the same as you mentioned above in windows and It ran successfully. So I have to do it again on linux, right?

Comment: no SSH. http://laravel.io/forum/02-26-2014-installing-laravel-on-server-without-ssh .

Comment: Well, if you don't have SSH access you WILL need to upload the whole thing manually. Which isn't that much of a problem, but it will take some time depending on your connection.

Comment: It's not professional. Why do I have to upload the parts that are already uploaded? Do you know which parts do I have to upload to make it works?

Comment: If you don't have SSH access I don't see many options besides uploading it manually. Yes, it's not "professional" and it might be a mess. If you want to do things professionally you WILL NEED SSH. I can't tell you what to upload and what not though, you will have to decide that for yourself based on your project. If you are on cPanel, you can use WEB SSH access btw.

Comment: Well, I'm glad the "expert" solved the question then.